# Change shipping method names in email templates in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am using matrixrates for shipping methods for my store. For some methods I have the same name but different prices, like "Standard" for above $350 and "Standard" for below $350. So programmatically I have distinct these two by putting ":2" with the below rate. so it becomes "Standard:2" I have successfully modified the front and backend to display "Standard" for both rates but in email send to customer "Standard:2" is sending. So I goes to the code deeply. New order email template is in locale/template/emai/sales/new_order.html, and for shipping details this function is used.

```
{{var order.getShippingDescription()}}
```

I found this function in Core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/progress.php. But by changing the return value, does not effect the shipping description in email. I am wondering where this function "getShippingDescription()" is so I can modify it.

Comment: FYI, Magento now has its own StackExchange site: http://magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: That's Great. How I can shipt it to that site?

Comment: Just flag it and request it be migrated

Comment: Thanks John, I have duplicated it on magento site.